# Travis CI building PHP project and pulling dependencies from Composer, tries to use git@ instead of https

Tags: php, git, composer-php, travis-ci, packagist

**Background**

We have a [PHP project](https://github.com/edmondscommerce/doctrine-static-meta) that was working fine with [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/edmondscommerce/doctrine-static-meta) until a certain point and since then has totally stopped working. The project is simply failing to build with Composer.

**Details**

The last successful build was:
[this one](https://travis-ci.org/edmondscommerce/doctrine-static-meta/builds/346190110)

The most recent failed build was:
[this one, in the branch `Naming Collisions`](https://travis-ci.org/edmondscommerce/doctrine-static-meta/jobs/350745120) which is [this commit](https://github.com/edmondscommerce/doctrine-static-meta/tree/0653cbd39b8545314bd0af184db14351c24e7d9d)

The error that keeps coming up is:

```
Failed to execute git clone --mirror 'git@github.com:edmondscommerce/Faker.git' '/home/travis/.composer/cache/vcs/git-github.com-edmondscommerce-Faker.git/'
```

latest branch is [`NamingCollisions`](https://github.com/edmondscommerce/doctrine-static-meta/tree/NamingCollisions), this is the [latest commit](https://github.com/edmondscommerce/doctrine-static-meta/tree/add328d26f787281fe89426a00fa0aab4cec81e8)

Notice in the [composer.json](https://github.com/edmondscommerce/doctrine-static-meta/blob/0653cbd39b8545314bd0af184db14351c24e7d9d/composer.json) we are using a [fork](https://github.com/edmondscommerce/Faker) for the [Faker library](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker):

```
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://github.com/edmondscommerce/Faker.git"
    }
  ],
```

This all works fine for our local tests, it only fails in Travis.

**Things we have tried:**

- flushing Travis caches
- clearing composer caches before doing the install - [`.travis.bash`](https://github.com/edmondscommerce/doctrine-static-meta/blob/0653cbd39b8545314bd0af184db14351c24e7d9d/.travis.bash)
- adding:

```
 "github-protocols": ["https"]
```

to the [composer.json](https://github.com/edmondscommerce/doctrine-static-meta/blob/0653cbd39b8545314bd0af184db14351c24e7d9d/composer.json)

- Hoping it will just go away...

No luck so far.

Unfortunately we're now just testing locally and ignoring Travis because it is consistently failing now even though the code is working fine.

Hopefully one of you readers can help figure this one out!

**What we went with**

In the end we decided to add `"no-api": true` to the `repositories` config as suggested by Everon.

This forces composer to no longer make use the github API ([docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md)):

> If you set the no-api key to true on a github repository it will clone the repository as it would with any other git repository instead of using the GitHub API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a look in to this and it isn't an issue with Travis itself.

After looking in to Travis and running the Travis environment locally in a Docker instance I was able to reproduce the issue.

Travis is complaining that it can not authenticate through at Github.

You need to use a Travis environment variable that can then be used to set the access token so that Composer can do what is required to install the VCS repository fork of Faker.

You can define the variable in the settings for your repository in Travis, it is then available as a standard Bash variable to be used in your travis `before_script` array or in your shell scripts.

Token from the build log:

```
Setting environment variables from repository settings
$ export GITHUB_TOKEN=[secure]
```

You define the required access token here:
https://github.com/settings/tokens/new?scopes=repo

And can then set it in the before script like so:

```
before_script:
  - composer config github-oauth.github.com ${GITHUB_TOKEN};
  - bash -x .travis.bash
```

Another option is to add "no-api" to your Faker fork - See below.

```
...
"repositories": [
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://github.com/edmondscommerce/Faker.git",
      "no-api": true
    }
]
...
```

Build (failed but has past the point you were having issues with)
https://travis-ci.org/everon/doctrine-static-meta/jobs/352620456